# Missing annotations for retrofit interace when using minifyEnabled

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2, android-r8

When running a build without `minifyEnabled` (debug build) everything works just fine, but when building with `minifyEnabled` there is a runtime error when calling to `Repository.getData`.

The error is about missing annotations `GET`, `PUT` etc.

There are two retrofit2 interfaces that has one super interface:

```kotlin
interface Api1 : Api {
    @GET("/api/v1/data")
    override suspend fun loadData(): List<Entry>
}

interface Api2 : Api {
    @GET("/api/v1/data2")
    override suspend fun loadData(): List<Entry>
}

interface Api {
    suspend fun loadData(): List<Entry>
}
```

There is a dagger2 module, that provides retrofit for this interfaces:

```kotlin
    @Provides
    fun provideApi1(retrofit: Retrofit): Api1 = retrofit.create(Api1::class.java)

    @Provides
    fun provideApi2(retrofit: Retrofit): Api2 = retrofit.create(Api2::class.java)
```

Somewere in repository there is such a call:

```kotlin
class RepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    val api1: Api1,
    val api2: Api2
) : Repository {

    fun getData(param: Boolean) = flow {
        val api = if (param) api1 else api2
        emit(api.loadData())
    }

}
```

I've tried to add keepclasses for annotations and for the interfaces to proguard rules. It doesn't help.

Comment: Please check out https://issuetracker.google.com/248203227#comment3 to see if that is the same issue you are running into. Retrofit has added better rules for services with hierachies, https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/3782, so also check your version of retrofit.

Comment: @sgjesse , Thank you for your comment. It has something in common but I can't say it is the same problem as I have annotations in child interfaces, not in parent. And I've tried to keep all these interfaces with proguard rules with no effect on result.
I've fixed my issue by rewriting code, but it is still interesting what is the cause of the problem.
When I have time, will run some tests and get back here with results.